# unable to print dropdown value using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a code and I am selecting a dropdown and when I click the button I want to print the value in console, but it is printing `null`.

Below is my code.

```
<form name="formSec" id="formSec">
        <div class="bodytag1">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">Breaks</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Break Task</td>
                    <td><select id="task" name="task"
                        onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                            <option value="break" id="break">Break</option>
                            <option value="ORD" id="ORD">ORD Meetings</option>
                            <option value="Training" id="Training">Training</option>
                            <option value="project" id="project">Adhoc Project</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>SubTask</td>
                    <td><select id="subtask" name="subtask">
                            <option value="Subtask">Subtask</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Start" name="Start" id="Start" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" id="Stop" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here is my js

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSFiles/myCssFile.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
        document.getElementById("subtask").length = 0;
        switch (listindex) {
        case "break":
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
                    "Please select Break type");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option(
                    "Casual Break ", "Casual Break");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[2] = new Option(
                    "Lunch Break", "Lunch Break");
            break;
        case "ORD":
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
                    "Please select type of Meeting", "");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option("Calls",
                    "Calls");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[2] = new Option(
                    "Team Meeting", "Team Meeting");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[3] = new Option(
                    "Thomson Activity (Fire Drill, RnR)",
                    "Thomson Activity (Fire Drill, RnR)");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[4] = new Option(
                    "System Downtime", "System Downtime");

            break;
        case "Training":
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
                    "Please select Type of Training", "");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option(
                    "EDP Training", "EDP Training");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[2] = new Option(
                    "Process Training", "Process Training");

            break;
        case "project":
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
                    "Please select type of Project", "");
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option(
                    "Others", "Others");
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = $('#formSec');
    var task = $('#task');
    var subtask = $('#subtask');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Start').on("click", function() {
            console.log(task);
            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "UpdateTime",
                data : form.serialize(),
                success : function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        alert("worked");
                    }
                    //$('#result').attr("value", result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: FYI: `javascript: ` is useless in the onchange event

Comment: Hi @epascarello, thanks for this, But I'm confused on where there is this `onChange` going to impact/get the result, I'm trying to print the value when I click on `Start` button

Comment: Has nothing to do with that, just giving you a pointer.

Comment: Does this mean that without this `onChange`, I won't be getting the result of what I'm trying to achieve? (Just want to confirm)

Comment: You really really should cache `var subtask = document.getElementById("subtask")`, instead of making one request to the DOM per line of code.

Comment: Where does this script live? Is it in the head or at the end of the body?

Comment: In `<head>` section

Comment: Well than you are reading the input before it is rendered to the page.

Comment: @epascarello, Hey Thank you verymuch, moving this code to `<body>` worked :-)

Comment: Or reference the elements on document ready. Basically you are trying to reference `var form = $('#formSec');
    var task = $('#task');
    var subtask = $('#subtask');` before they are rendered to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the references to the elements inside the document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#formSec');
    var task = $('#task');
    var subtask = $('#subtask');
    $('#Start').on("click", function() {
        console.log(task);
    });
});
```

Now when you click on the button, it will have a reference to the task input. Other option, if you want to have them as globals is to move the script so it appears after the elements you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the selected option first, and then you can get the value of that option.

You can use this code, for example:

```
var selectedOption = task.find("option:selected");
console.log(selectedOption.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log(task.val())` instead of `console.log(task)`

```js
function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
  document.getElementById("subtask").length = 0;
  switch (listindex) {
    case "break":
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
        "Please select Break type");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option(
        "Casual Break ", "Casual Break");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[2] = new Option(
        "Lunch Break", "Lunch Break");
      break;
    case "ORD":
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
        "Please select type of Meeting", "");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option("Calls",
        "Calls");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[2] = new Option(
        "Team Meeting", "Team Meeting");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[3] = new Option(
        "Thomson Activity (Fire Drill, RnR)",
        "Thomson Activity (Fire Drill, RnR)");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[4] = new Option(
        "System Downtime", "System Downtime");

      break;
    case "Training":
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
        "Please select Type of Training", "");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option(
        "EDP Training", "EDP Training");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[2] = new Option(
        "Process Training", "Process Training");

      break;
    case "project":
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0] = new Option(
        "Please select type of Project", "");
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[0].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("subtask").options[1] = new Option(
        "Others", "Others");
      break;

  }
  return true;
}

var form = $('#formSec');
var task = $('#task');
var subtask = $('#subtask');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Start').on("click", function() {
    console.log(task.val());
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "UpdateTime",
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
          alert("worked");
        }
        //$('#result').attr("value", result);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formSec" id="formSec">
  <div class="bodytag1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">Breaks</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Break Task</td>
        <td>
          <select id="task" name="task" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option value="break" id="break">Break</option>
            <option value="ORD" id="ORD">ORD Meetings</option>
            <option value="Training" id="Training">Training</option>
            <option value="project" id="project">Adhoc Project</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SubTask</td>
        <td>
          <select id="subtask" name="subtask">
            <option value="Subtask">Subtask</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Start" name="Start" id="Start" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" id="Stop" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```